# equivalences induced by functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, functors, derived-categories

I'm reading the paper [Deriving Auslander's formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7051.pdf). In some parts of this paper, we can see equivalences which are induced by some functors. For example, at the end of the page 3, the author says: "*the inclusion functor
$~\mathsf{mod~C} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Mod~C}~$ induces an equivalence
$$\mathsf{Ind~mod~C \overset{\sim} \longrightarrow Mod~C}$$*". In general, how can we get an equivalence from a functor? are there any theorems? If yes, could you please give me some references for this subject? Thanks in advance. 
 
$\mathsf{C}$ : A category (usually additive) 
$\mathsf{Mod~C}$ : The category of additive functors $\mathsf{F:C^{OP} \longrightarrow Ab}$ 
$\mathsf{mod~C}$ : The category of finitely presented functors $\mathsf{F:C^{OP} \longrightarrow Ab}$ 
$\mathsf{Ind~mod~C}$ : The full subcategory of $\mathsf{((mod~C)^{OP},Ab)}$ consisting of functors which can be expressed as filtered colimits of representable ones.

Comment: Sanity check: do you know what an equivalence of categories is?

Comment: @Hurkyl. Yes, I know. But I don't know how this equivalence is induced by this functor.

Comment: There are a few errors in your question as stated already. Ind mod C isn't a subcategory of mod C (actually, there's a canonical inclusion in the *other* direction), and "finitely generated" hasn't been defined (and in any case, the author says finitely *presented*).

Comment: @Billy. Thanks. I edited that mistake. A finitely generated functor F, here, is one for which there exists an exact sequence $(-,A) \longrightarrow F \longrightarrow 0$.

Comment: Ah, I see how I misunderstood the question. I can't find a reference (surprisingly, [nLab's page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object) doesn't explicitly state it), but I think there's supposed to be a natural equivalence between the category of functors $C \to D$ where $D$ has all filtered colimits and of filtered colimit preserving functors $Ind(C) \to D$, or something along those lines.

Comment: @Hurkyl It's in Remark 2.3, unfortunately left as obvious, though it's not. The textbook reference for these matters is Adamek-Rosicky, locally presentable and accessible categories.