# extending functors

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, abelian-categories, functors, additive-categories

In "[Functors on locally finitely presented additive categories](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm75/cm75110.pdf)", by H. Krause, one can read (in page 108):

> Proposition 2.3. There is, up to equivalence, a bijective correspondence
> between (skeletally small) additive categories with split idempotents
> and pseudo-kernels and (skeletally small) abelian categories with sufficiently
> many projectives. The correspondence is given by: $$\mathsf{C \longmapsto mod~C} ~~~~~ and ~~~~~ \mathcal{A} \longmapsto \mathsf{proj}(\mathcal{A})$$

in proof, the author says:

> If $\mathsf{C}$ is an additive category with split idempotents and pseudokernels,
> then $\mathsf{mod~C}$  is abelian and the representable functors $\mathsf{Hom(−,X)}$ are precisely the projective objects in $\mathsf{mod~C}$ by Yoneda’s lemma. Conversely,
> given an abelian category A with sufficiently many projectives,
> $\mathsf{proj}(\mathcal{A})$ has pseudo-kernels and the inclusion $\mathsf{proj}(\mathcal{A}) \to \mathcal{A}$ extends to a
> functor $\mathsf{mod(proj}(\mathcal{A})) \to \mathcal{A}$ which is an equivalence.

I tried very much and studied different books and articles about this subject but I cannot understand how I can extend a functor (the following part in proof):

> ... the inclusion $\mathsf{proj}(\mathcal{A}) \to \mathcal{A}$ extends to a
> functor $\mathsf{mod(proj}(\mathcal{A})) \to \mathcal{A}$ which is an equivalence.

and also, I cannot understand why the new functor is an equivalence. there are lots of examples like this that I cannot understand. For instance, in my past question in the forum, "[equivalences induced by functors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791555/equivalences-induced-by-functors)", it is not clear for me how $\mathsf{mod~C} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Mod~C}$ extends to $\mathsf{Ind~mod~C \overset{\sim} \longrightarrow Mod~C}$ and why this is an equivalence. I really need some help to understand these kind of proofs by your comments or recommending some good books or articles. 
 **Notes:**

$\mathcal{A}$ : An abelian category 
$\mathsf{C}$ : An additive category 
$\mathsf{proj}(\mathcal{A})$ : the full subcategory of $\mathcal{A}$ consisting of projective objects 
$\mathsf{Mod~C}$ : The category of additive functors $\mathsf{F:C^{OP}⟶Ab}$ 
$\mathsf{mod~C}$ : The full subcategory of $\mathsf{Mod~C}$ consisting of finitely presented objects 
$\mathsf{Ind~mod~C}$ : The full subcategory of $\mathsf{((mod~C)^{OP},Ab)}$ consisting of functors which can be expressed as filtered colimits of representable ones.

Comment: For existence the author uses the previously stated "Universal property 2.1". Another good reference to read about this correspondence is [Auslander: Coherent functors, 1966].

Comment: And it's an equivalence because having sufficiently many projectives here means exactly that everything is a cokernel of a map of projectives, and such cokernels are exactly what one adjoins to A in constructing A-mod. It seems you could remove the pseudo-kernels assumption on one side and the abelian assumption on the other to get a cleaner and more general statement.

Comment: @KevinCarlson If we remove abelian assumption, proj(A) is not additive anymore. right?

Comment: @math16 I don't see why not. It just won't have pseudo-kernels, as Krause says.

Comment: @KevinCarlson What is the additive structure on proj(A)? Shouldn't it be inherited from A?

Comment: Oh, yes. You still want to assume A is additive, just not necessarily abelian-sorry for the obscurity there.